# Using jupyter R kernel with visual studio code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter

For python jupyter notebooks I am currently using VSCode python extension. However I cannot find any way to use alternative kernels. I am interested in jupyter R kernel in particular.

Is there any way to work with jupyter notebooks using R kernel in VSCode?

Comment: Folks at Microsoft are on it. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5078#issuecomment-608175269

Comment: As of 2023, R Kernel for Jupyter Notebooks is supported in VS Code (reference to [Jupyter Extension for VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/113c3e54ac1d3cb81ab6473d1a5fa4a20cce4755/README.md#working-with-other-languages)).

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it is possible. It just requires an additional configuration to connect with the R kernel in VSCode.

It's worth noting that, if you prefer, you can use the notebook in [VSCode Insiders](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/notebooks-are-getting-revamped/) where there is native support for notebooks in many languages, including R.

---

If you're using Jupyter in **VSCode**, firstly install [IRkernel](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel) (R kernel).

According to the docs, run both lines to perform the installation:

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()  # to register the kernel in the current R installation
```

Now, you should:

1. Reload Window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to search for "Jupyter: Create New Blank Notebook"
   [image]
3. Click on the button right below ellipsis in upper right corner to choose kernel

   [image]
4. Switch to the desired kernel, in this case, R's [image]

That's it!

Comment: could you provide some info or link why is buggy about vs code and the integration with R kernel ? Maybe just not the case anymore ? Looks to me it works pretty well

Comment: Just in case that someone has the same trouble as me following the instructions without getting it to work: it might be necessary to call `IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)` , for me it did not show up in the list of kernels before.

Comment: Does this still work?

Comment: It still works in 2023 on vscode 1.81

Answer (score 2):

@testing_22 it works with me too

**just add some note from my experience**

It will failed If you run `IRkernel::installspec()` from RStudio or from Jupyter Conda environment failed way[image]

Please run this syntax with VSCode terminal

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

[image]

The rest is same, please restart VSCode and select "R" kernel from VSCode

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @essicolo, if you are 100% stuck on using vscode this is a no-go.

> [About kernels] Sorry, but as of right now this feature is only supported with Python. We are looking at supporting other languages in the future.
>
> Yeah, that's the case for now, even if you start an external server. I hate having to say that, as we really want to support more of the various language kernels. But we started out with a Python focus and we still are pretty locked into that for the near future. Polyglot support is coming, but it won't be right away

per Microsoft Employee IanMatthewHuff

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5109#issuecomment-480097310

---

preface - based on the phrasing of your question, I am making the assumption that you are trying to perform `IRkernel` in-line execution from your text ide without having to use a jupyter notebook / jupyterlab.

That said, if you're willing to go to the dark side, there might be some alternatives:

1. nteract's [Hydrogen kernel](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen) for Atom IDE - the only text ide that I'm aware of that still supports execution against `IRkernel`. I know, I know - it's not `vscode` but it's as close as you'll probably get for now.

[image]

2. TwoSigma's [Beaker notebook](https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx) - it's been a lonngggg time for me but this a branch of jupyter that used to support polyglot editing, I'm not sure if that's still supported and it seems like you aren't that interested in notebooks anyway.