# Add Jupyter kernel in Visual Studio Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia

Has anyone ever figured out how to add a Jupyter kernel in VS Code, such as R or Julia? This question has actually been asked 8 months ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497422/using-jupyter-r-kernel-with-visual-studio-code), but never had an anwser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jupyter R kernel with visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497422/using-jupyter-r-kernel-with-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2):

In November of 2020, a [Jupyter for VSCode Extension was unveiled](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/introducing-the-jupyter-extension-for-vs-code/).

> The Jupyter extension provides basic notebook support for any language kernel that is supported in Jupyter Notebooks today

So you will likely need to install `IJulia` still but the functionality should now exist.