# How to use jupyter notebook with R kernal in VS code?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

Now I can use jupyter lab with R kernal in a web browser and use VS Code to edit jupyter note book code with python kernal, is it possible to edit R code in VS Code with jupyter notebook mode? Thanks for the comments and solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jupyter R kernel with visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497422/using-jupyter-r-kernel-with-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. You just have to install [IRkernel](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel) (R kernel) first.

According to the docs, run both lines

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()  # to register the kernel in the current R installation
```

Then, restart your VSCode and:

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to search for "Jupyter: Create New Blank Notebook"
  [image]
- Click on the button right below ellipsis in upper right corner to choose kernel

  [image]
- Switch to the desired kernel, in this case R's [image]

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

@testing_22 it works with me too

**just add some note from my experience**

It will failed If you run `IRkernel::installspec()` from RStudio or from Jupyter Conda environment
[image: failed way]

Please run this syntax with VSCode terminal

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

[image]

The rest is same, please restart VSCode and select "R" kernel from VSCode