# Jupyter R Kernel in VS Code with Anaconda Environment: Failed to start the Kernel

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

**Summary**

- Installed R kernel in Anaconda environment
- Works with Anaconda's browser Jupyter notebook, but not VS Code.

**Details**

I am trying to set up VS Code to recognize my R kernel for use with Jupyter Notebooks. The steps I have followed are as follows:

1. Create a new R environment (via the Anaconda interface... Rstudio works just fine).
2. Using the command line interface with the above environment activated, ensure Jupyter is installed: `conda install jupyter`
3. Install irkernel: `conda install -c r r-irkernel`
4. Run R from command line and initialize irkernel:

```
R
> IRkernel::installspec()
```

5. Open VS Code and create a new notebook. Select the R kernel that appears, and run a basic commannd in the first cell: `file.path(getwd())`

These follow the steps [here](https://www.practicaldatascience.org/html/jupyter_r_notebooks.html), and in other Stackoverflow posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540700/how-to-use-jupyter-notebook-with-r-kernal-in-vs-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497422/using-jupyter-r-kernel-with-visual-studio-code)).

Unfortunately, I cannot get the kernel to work. The above code in item 5 results in the following error:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
The kernel died. Error: ... View Jupyter log for further details.
```

There is a copy of the log available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fpj6SedsCiADOB2c1pHVQ9-_tVjQ3yM-/view?usp=share_link) (should be visible to everyone). The notebook is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16XkdWkwcnNjFnJmWx1t3DZtvmDY7KoNl/view?usp=share_link) (but is literally just the one line of code mentioned above).

My hypothesis is that `IRkernel::installspec()` installs the kernel in a different location than the conda environment. The kernel is installed in `C:\Users\aaron\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\ir`, while in VS Code the kernel selected is in `C:\Users\aaron\.conda\envs\rstudio\lib\R\bin\x64\R` (the environment name is `rstudio`).

However, when I open Jupyter notebook via the Anaconda interface (not VS Code... i.e. the browser version), everything works just fine. The same code (`file.path(getwd())`) returns the appropriate `'C:/Users/aaron'`.

I am sure I have done something silly wrong, and appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Did you every find a solution? I am facing a similar issue.