# Vscode is giving parse error while running multiple lines of R code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

[image: Example]

Am not exactly sure what's causing the those extra spaces in the end. Any help will be appreciated.
Am using VScodium and R language server is installed.
I used the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497422/using-jupyter-r-kernel-with-visual-studio-code) to get R kernel working with VScode.

edit: VScode insiders works properly. Still I wanted to try VSCodium since vscode worked on my other machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried VSCode insiders and it worked alright. I guess there is some problem with VScode and its fork Vscodium.